# Logon fail trying to connect to shared folders on Xubuntu 20.04 from Seagate GoFlex media player

Tags: samba

I upgraded from Xubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 using the 'update-manager -d' command. Since then the shortcuts I created on my Seagate GoFlex media player produce a 'Logon Fail' message whereas they worked fine before. I feel sure this is going to be related to Samba in some way but I don't know how to find out for sure. My smb.conf file already has the line 'client min protocol = NT1 in the 'global' section so I thought this should be OK for older devices limitations. I tried setting up the shortcuts using 'guest' and 'nobody' but the problem persists.
Any ideas how I can make it work again, please?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my problem in this article: [Broken samba shares](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2432909)